# ISSET function undefined variables variables

Tags: php, isset, notice

*Hello i have problem with isset id like someone to help me fixin this problem. Its this problem* ***Notice:*** ***Undefined variable: v in*** ***C:\xampp\htdocs\something\something2.php on line 17*** and my code is :

```
<form id="priklad" method="post">
    <label>Obvod kruhu:</label>
    <?php IF (isset($_POST['v'])) {
            $_POST['v'];
        }
    ?>
    <label>r:</label><input type="text" name="r"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Vypočti"/></br>
    <label><?php echo 2*$v;?> cm</label>
</form>
```

EDIT:

```
<form id="priklad" method="post">
    <label>Obvod kruhu:</label>
    <?php If (is_numeric($_POST['v'])) {
            $v = $_POST['v'];
        }
    ?>
    <label>v:</label><input type="text" name="v"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Vypočti"/></br>
    <label><?php echo 2*$v;?> cm</label>
</form>
```

and im getting these errors
Notice: Undefined index: v in C:\xampp\htdocs\something\something2.php on line 11 and Notice: Undefined variable: v in C:\xampp\htdocs\something\something2.php on line 17

Comment: `<?php echo 2*$v;?>` <- here, and what should this do `$_POST['v'];` ?

Comment: I don't see any `$v = ...` In your code anywhere, and neither does your code, hence the error.

Comment: oh sorry it didnt copy my whole code.. there is like one more input with the name "v"

Comment: I think you have forget to write $v=$_POST['v']; !!

Comment: @StarScrime please edit your original question rather than adding code to your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @StarScrime I've updated my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your value `v` is not the same as the implied value of `$_POST['v']`  . As stated by Tim, there is no `$v =` statement so in effect your echo output is outputting nothing multiplied by 2.

This throws a warning which you have picked up.

So a solution could be:

```
<form id="priklad" method="post">
    <label>Obvod kruhu:</label>
    <?php If (is_numeric($_POST['v'])) {
            $v = $_POST['v'];
        }
    ?>
    <label>r:</label><input type="text" name="r"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Vypočti"/></br>
    <label><?php echo 2*$v;?> cm</label>
</form>
```

I have used `is_numeric` as you are using the echo to produce a value x 2 so makes more sense to check V is a number rather than a string.

### UPDATE

Ok, first stop then is to see what is on line 11? is it `$_POST['v']` ? If so then you can work back to the source of the cause - replace the line 11 (comment it out, don't delete it) with something like:

`print_r($_POST);`

This will output all values associated with the array $_POST.

If you do not see a value for 'v' (and I guess you probably won't) then that means this value wasn't set in the previous HTML page so go back and check that your form submits an input such as:

```
<input name='v' value="something">
```

Undefined index means the array ( $_POST ) does not contain any information stored under `$_POST['v']`.

Can you confirm your POST is as intended, and that you do want post which means you need to submit the form rather than GET or another method, such as `index.php?v=10` ?

The Notice:

PHP does have notice statements but they're *only* notices, they are not errors or even warnings, it's just PHP telling you what's going on. This will not break your code, but it could be nice to add this line *above* your IF statement:

```
$v = 0;
```

This establishes the variable $v and gives it a value. Which if $_POST['v'] exists is then updated to reflect that.

Comment: OP has a input with the name v: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282233/isset-function-undefined-variables-variables#comment44918848_28282233

Comment: And after that im getting another error Notice: Undefined index: v in C:\xampp\htdocs\something\something2.php on line 11 and Notice: Undefined variable: v in C:\xampp\htdocs\something\something2.php on line 17

Comment: It's not stated on his question. And fits the error message. Anyhow, his comment was written as I was writing my answer so I will update my answer as he updates his question....

Answer (score 0):

What's actually happening with that error is that your variable `$v` isn't being initialized because the code has not enter the `if` condition.

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['v'])){
   $v = $_POST['v'];
}
```

You're assuming that the condition `is_numeric($_POST..)` is `true` but it might not be, which means that the variable `$v` is never initialized. Therefore is pretty normal the error you are having.

You can continue with your condition but you must check for the variable **after** it.

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['v'])){
   $v = $_POST['v'];
}

echo 2 * (isset($v) ? $v : 1);
```

The above code might be improved. A better code/logic would be you to set up the default value of the variable in case the `is_numeric` returns false.

```
$v = 1; // default value

if(is_numeric($_POST['v'])){
  $v = $_POST['v'];
}

echo 2 * $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like this.

```
<form id="priklad" method="post">
    <label>Obvod kruhu:</label>
    <?php 
    $v = '';
    If (is_numeric($_POST['v'])) {
            $v = $_POST['v'];
        }
    ?>
    <label>v:</label><input type="text" name="v"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Vypočti"/></br>
    <label><?php echo (($v)? 2*$v : 'Its not numeric value');?> cm</label>
  </form>
```